# PInvoke Array Marshalling Failure

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, memcpy

I have the following C++ function exported in a DLL:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool GetResolutionArray(int32_t adapterIndex, int32_t outputIndex, uint32_t arrayLength, Resolution outResolutionArr[]) {
        memcpy_s(
        outResolutionArr, 
        sizeof(Resolution) * arrayLength,
        RENDER_COMPONENT.GetResolutionArray(adapterIndex, outputIndex),
        RENDER_COMPONENT.GetOutput(adapterIndex, outputIndex).NumResolutions * sizeof(Resolution)
        );
    return true;
}
```

And, the matching extern function declaration in C#:

```
[DllImport(InteropUtils.RUNTIME_DLL, EntryPoint = "GetResolutionArray", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern bool _GetResolutionArray(int adapterIndex, int outputIndex, uint resolutionArrayLength, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), In, Out] ref Resolution[] resolutions);
```

However, when I attempt to use this function as below, the program crashes with a FatalExecutionEngineError (indicating I corrupted something somewhere I guess) (error code 0xc0000005, i.e. access violation):

```
Resolution[] resolutions = new Resolution[outOutputDesc.NumResolutions];
if (!_GetResolutionArray(outAdapterDesc.AdapterIndex, outOutputDesc.OutputIndex, (uint) resolutions.Length, ref resolutions)) {
    EnginePipeline.TerminateWithError("Internal engine call failed: _GetResolutionArray");
}
```

I strongly suspect that my call to `memcpy_s` is causing the access violation, but I can't see how or why, and I therefore reason that perhaps the marshalling is going wrong somewhere.

Thank you.

Comment: Try marshalling just OUT instead of in and out for your return parameter.  Also, What is EnginePipeline.TerminateWithError()?  I'd soften that and make sure to add the full error message in the question here.

Comment: @ebyrob Tried it, no effect.

Comment: Possibly `sizeof(Resolution) C++` is different from `sizeof(Resolution) C#`.

Comment: @wdosanjos I printed out sizeof(Resolution) on the C# and C++ side, both are 16 bytes.

Comment: doh, `, Resolution outResolutionArr[]` in parameter list... passing array in DLL method call, talk about dicey.  Needs to go back and forth as `*`.  For one thing, you'd always have to pass same number of resolutions from `C#` every call.  In fact, I think the way you have it `C#` will pass pointer while `C++` expects an array parameter (not that I really understand that C++ concept but it's very different).

Comment: @ebyrob I changed `, Resolution outResolutionArr[]` to `, Resolution* outResolutionArr` but it made no difference.

Comment: Remove *ref* from the C# declaration, an array is already pass by reference.

Comment: @HansPassant Brilliant, that did it - feel free to answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: I don't want to post an answer to this.  There is no explanation for this mistake triggering an FEEE, it shouldn't.  I don't want to increase the noise level on FEEEs, they are very hard to diagnose and this one was way too easy.

Comment: The structs in question have custom packing (both in C++ and C#), that's all I can think of that might evoke an FEEE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array parameter is declared incorrectly. A C# array is already a reference and so you don't need the `ref`. Declare it like this:

```
[DllImport(InteropUtils.RUNTIME_DLL, EntryPoint = "GetResolutionArray", 
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern bool _GetResolutionArray(int adapterIndex, 
    int outputIndex, uint resolutionArrayLength, Resolution[] resolutions);
```